# Jersey + Guice + Tomcat producing 404 when served with something other than root directory

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, guice

I have a resource that looks like this:

```
@Path("/Resources/Console")
public class ConsoleResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public String post(/* */) {
        /* */
    }

}
```

Whenever my JerseyServletModule is configured as follows, the services work:

```
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(ConsoleResource.class);

    bind(MessageBodyReader.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    bind(MessageBodyWriter.class).to(JacksonJsonProvider.class);

    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
}
```

But things like index.html don't.  Changing `"/*"` to `"/Resources/*"` causes things like index.html to work, again, but then `ConsoleResource`'s `@POST` method doesn't work (I get a 404 whenever I access `/Resources/Console`).  I assume I want to get the latter working (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097238/jersey-guice-using-non-root-request-paths)).  Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422660/jersey-servlet-mapping-causes-404-error-for-static-resources/12428843#12428843 ?

Comment: @condit: That wasn't exactly what I ended up doing, but it pointed me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being the server running static content through the various filters and whatnot.  By editing the web.xml file to be the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And abiding by the convention that my resources would have `/Resources/` as a prefix to their path, static content gets through the Guice filter.